# Remove spinner dialog background

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I'm trying to style a custom spinner in dialog mode, but whatever I do I can't get rid of the white background.

This is my spinner.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    />
```

The items in my spinner all have a transparent background, as I don't want a background for each item, but one for the whole dialog.
I found out I can set a background for all items, by overriding android:listViewStyle in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/myListView</item>
</style>

<style name="myListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_dropdown</item>
</style>
```

[image: how to remove the background in the corners?]

But even after that, there is still another background behind the list. I guessed it's from the dialog the spinner uses, so I added android:alertDialogStyle to my theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/myListView</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/myDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="myDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

but it made no difference. How do I get rid of this white background in the corners?

Comment: can you add the code of dialog creation and show

Comment: I don't create any dialog, I assume there is a dialog created by Android, because the spinner mode is set to "dialog"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503667/9701793

Comment: No it doesn't. The firsrt answer suggests to remove spinnerMode = "dialog", but I need it as dialog. The second one didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by using a cardview.
This is the code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                 android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                 android:layout_margin="16dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/background_dropdown"
                 android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```